# Lable in button

Tags: javafx

У меня есть красивый лейбл, и красивая кнопка. Вопрос просто в возможности. Можно ли лейбл поместить в кнопку? И если да, то пожалуйста пример, если нет, то как сделать красивым текст внутри кнопки причем речь о эффектах, а не просто о выборе шрифта, если можно то пожалуйста пример.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setGraphic( niceLabel );
//button.setPadding( new Insets( -1 ) );
```